# Jordan decomposition for simple Lie algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a simple complex Lie algebra. Let us fix a Cartan, a Borel, and generators $x_\alpha$ of negative simple roots. Then $N:=\sum x_\alpha$
is a principal (=regular) nilpotent element. Now suppose $X$ is an element of the Cartan.

Question: What is the Jordan decomposition of $N+X$?

In Type $A$, one finds that $N+X$ is conjugate to $N'+X$ where $N'$ is the principal nilpotent of the centraliser $C_{\mathfrak{g}}(X)$. The expression $N'+X$ is then the Jordan decomposition of $N+X$. (Since $N'$ is nilpotent, $X$ is semisimple, and they commute). Does something similar happen in general types?

Comment: In type A, my impression is that "generically", the Jordan decomposition of $N+X$ is $0+(N+X)$ since $N+X$ is semisimple.